# System is showing 2 cores present but showing same core_id for two cores

Tags: 14.04

In  Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, I have two cores but each core has same core_id. What is the problem?

```
$ nproc 
2
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core_id'
core_id :0
core_id :0
```

And as asked:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x1
cpu MHz     : 2199.998
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca 
cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp 
lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq vmx 
ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt 
tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 
3dnowprefetch xsaveopt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase 
tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap
bogomips    : 4399.99
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x1
cpu MHz     : 2199.998
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca 
cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp 
lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq vmx 
ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt 
tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 
3dnowprefetch xsaveopt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase 
tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap
bogomips    : 4399.99
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

cmdline output:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline

BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-125-generic root=LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs 
ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting.  http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code. Also, your CPU probably has something like Intel's Hyper-Threading (2 logical cores for a physical core). Post the rest of `cpuinfo`, so we can confirm from the hardware description.

Comment: please edit your question and add the entire output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. Currently we do not have enough information to answer, but I would guess that you actually have 1 core and 2 threads per core for 2 CPUs.

Comment: What is your kernel command line? `cat /proc/cmdline` . Are cores somehow turned off in the BIOS? for that processor you should have 12 cores and 2 threads per core, or 24 CPUs per package, and you appear to have 2 packages.